# How to navigate to another screen after axios action dispatch in reducer in react- native

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I understand that this.props.isValidUser gets updated after action dispatches the axios promise. if the user is not valid is shows message. If the user is valid user, I want to navigate to another screen to enter pin. How do I navigate to another screen after I get axios result from action?

types.js

```js
export const VALIDATE_USER = "VALIDATE_USER";
export const VALIDATE_PIN = "VALIDATE_PIN";
export const GET_ERRORS = "GET_ERRORS";
```

Reducer.js

```js
import { VALIDATE_USER, VALIDATE_PIN, GET_ERRORS } from "../actions/types.js";

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case VALIDATE_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        isValidUser: (action.payload == true) ? true : false,
        Id: action.employeeId
      };
    case VALIDATE_PIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        isValidPin: action.payload,
        action: "VALIDATE_PIN",

      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

action.js

```js
import { GET_ERRORS, VALIDATE_USER, VALIDATE_PIN, } from "./types";

export const validateUser = (empId) => dispatch => {
  axios.get(`${API}/api/Account/ValidateMobileAppUser?employeeId=${empId}`)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: VALIDATE_USER,
        payload: res.data,
        Id: empId,
      });

    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({
        type: VALIDATE_USER,
        payload: false,
        Id: empId
      });

    });
};
```

Login.js

```js
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { validateUser } from "../actions/authActions";

class Login extends PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      employeeId: "",
      pin: "",
      isValidUser: false,
    };
    this.onValidateUser = this.onValidateUser.bind(this);
    this.onEmployeeId = this.onEmployeeId.bind(this);
  }

  onEmployeeId(employeeId) {
    this.setState({ employeeId });
  }

  onValidateUser() {
    this.props.validateUser(this.state.employeeId);
  }

  render() {
    const { loading } = this.props.loading;
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.login} >
        <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
          <Block padding={[10, theme.sizes.base * 2]} onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
            <Block middle>
              <Input
                placeholder={this.state.placeholder}
                keyboardType={this.state.keyboardType}
                style={[styles.input]}
                value={this.state.employeeId}
                onChangeText={this.onEmployeeId}
              />
              {(this.props.isValidUser == false) ? (
                <Text center style={{ color: "#C00000", marginTop: 15, fontSize: 14 }}>
                  Employee Id  not registered. Please contact HR.
                </Text>
              ) : ""}
              <Button
                gradient
                style={styles.loginButton}
                onPress={this.onValidateUser}
              >
                <Text white center>
                  Login
                </Text>
              </Button>
            </Block>

            <Button
              onPress={() => this.onGoToStep(1)}
              style={{
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderRadius: 30,
                borderColor: "#E46932"
              }}
            >
              <Text gray caption center style={{ color: "#E46932" }}>
                Don't have an account? Sign Up
               </Text>
            </Button>
          </Block>
        </ScrollView>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}

Login.propTypes = {
  validateUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

function reducerCallback(state, ownProps) {
  if (state.auth.isValidUser == true) {
    ownProps.navigation.navigate("mPin", { Id: state.auth.employeeId, type: "LOGIN" });
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  auth: reducerCallback(state, ownProps),
  isValidUser: state.auth.isValidUser,
  errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    validateUser,
  }
)(Login);
```

`this.props.isValidUser == false`   tells me if the user is valid or not. But if the user is valid I'm navigating to another screen using `reducerCallback()` function. I'm not aware if this is the correct way to do so. My question is how to I navigate to another screen after I get return result from async axios action and How to I set local state using setState when I get callback from axios dispatch. Please guide

Comment: You should go for [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) instead of useState for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to below code:

login.js:

```
onValidateUser() {
    this.props.validateUser({
      empId: this.state.employeeId,
      onSuccess: () => {
        //Navigate to other screen
      },
      onFailure: () => {
        //Alert error message
      },
    });
 }
```

Action.js:

```
export const validateUser = ({empId, onSuccess, onFailure}) => dispatch => {
  axios
    .get(
      `${API}/api/Account/ValidateMobileAppUser?employeeId=${empId}`
    )
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: VALIDATE_USER,
        payload: res.data,
        Id: empId,
       });
       onSuccess();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({
        type: VALIDATE_USER,
        payload: false,
        Id: empId
      });
      onFailure()
    });
};
```